# Even-though i don't have constructor in my code i am getting error the constructor should be payable if you send value

Tags: solidity

This is my code in Solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract WithdrawalContract {
   mapping(address => uint) buyers;

   function buy()public payable {
      require(msg.value > 0);
      buyers[msg.sender] = msg.value;
   }
   function withdraw()public {
      uint amount = buyers[msg.sender];
      require(amount > 0);
      buyers[msg.sender] = 0;      
      require(msg.sender.send(amount));
   }
}
```

Below is the error i am getting. Not sure why it is asking for constructor

transact to WithdrawalContract.buy errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

That's just part of the error message Remix shows when a transaction reverts, presumably because that's a common mistake people make.

In your case, that's not the issue. My guess would be that you're calling `buy` and not attaching any ether, so the `require(msg.value > 0)` is causing the transaction to revert. In Remix, make sure you have a non-zero "value" in the upper right.